# parsing input in c++ for competitive programming

Tags: c++, parsing

How to parse input like for example:

```
[[1,3,5,7],[10,11,16,20],[23,30,34,60]]
```

for 2d vector of `m x n` size. I have tried

```
char x;
vector<int> v;
vector<vector<int>> v_v;

vector<int> temp;

int br_op_cl = 0;
int row = 0;

while (cin >> x) {
    // cout << x << endl;
    if (x == '[' || x == '{') {
        // cout << "inside [" << endl;
        br_op_cl++;
        cout << "inside [ " << br_op_cl << endl;
    } else if (x == ']' || x == '}') {
        cout << "inside ] " << x << endl;
        br_op_cl--;
    } else if (x >= 0 && x != ',') {
        cout << "inside 0-9 " << x << endl;
        temp.push_back(x);
        if (br_op_cl % 2 != 0) {
            cout << br_op_cl << " inside br_op_cl " << '\n';
            v_v.push_back(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

and the output is

```
49 51 53 55 49 48 49 49 49 54 50 48 50 51 51 48 51 52 54 48
```

which is ascii values of the each digit.
Any help for how to read chars and int together and parsing techniques in c++

Comment: For that simple case, you could just extract only every digit from the input using e.g. `std::isdigit()` as condition. But I am not sure if that's really what you're after.

Comment: isdigit() is for one digit not for big numbers.

Comment: But you're requested to display ASCII values of single digits?? I am confused now. Just read from the stream char by char, check `isdigit()`, and `cout << (unsigned int)c` for the decimal value. No need to read _"big numbers"_ in 1st place. Or do you mean to do something else?

Comment: consider this vector ```[[1,3,5,7],[10,11,16,20],[23,30,34,60]]``` is given by user in run time. now I have to read this m x n 2D vector. to read I use temp vector and push it to 2D vector when ```[1,3,5,7]``` is done.

Comment: I would read the entire input into std::string, then use std regex library to split it into the strings corresponding to each row (like `[10,11,16,20]`), then parse each of such strings (maybe by repeated `std::find()`, but there are many other ways for this stage).

Comment: According to your question's title, please define `cp`.  Is it California Polytechnic university?  Is it the copy function?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews cp -> competitive programming

Comment: i think a switch would be more clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `[1,3,5,7]` to be a single row. Use `stringstream` to read this row. Then use another `stringstream` to read the content of this row.

`getline` will read each row until it hits `]`, another `getline` will read each column until it hits `]`.

Replace occurrences of `{`  with `[`, to make parsing easier.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "[[1,3,5,7],[10,11,16,20],[23,30,34,60]]";
    replace(str.begin(), str.end(), '{', '[');
    replace(str.begin(), str.end(), '}', ']');
    std::stringstream ss(str);
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> res;
    if (ss.get() != '[')
        return 0;
    char c;
    while (ss >> c && c != ']') {
        if (c == '[') {
            getline(ss, str, ']');
            std::stringstream scol(str);
            std::vector<int> vec;
            while (getline(scol, str, ','))
                vec.push_back(std::stoi(str));
            res.push_back(vec);
        }
    }
    for (auto& row : res) {
        for (auto& col : row) std::cout << col << ",";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```